# Strange behaviour on Pandas HDF5 - read_hdf not returning results

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, pytables

So I am trying to read a HDF5 file. I am reading from a column of string values but the column can contain values that are purely numeric too, however they must be treated as strings. For example user_value = 5RDFU, user_value = 12345 are both user IDs. However when querying like the following,

```
query_reporter = "{user_id}={user_value}".format(user_id='User ID', user_value=str(my_user_value))

# In the above code User ID is the column name and my_user_value can be 5RDFU, 12345 etc. 

data_frame = get_partial_hdf_node(K.hdf_store_path, query_reporter, key)

def get_partial_hdf_node(hdfstore, query, key):
   store = pd.HDFStore(hdfstore, mode='r')
   #data_frame = pd.read_hdf(hdfstore, key, where=query)
   data_frame = store.select(key, where=query)
   store.close()
   return data_frame
```

This works well for when user_value cannot be represented as a number. For example if it is 44567TY or so. But if the value can be represented as an integer it fails. 12345 fails with the following error.

```
TypeError: Cannot compare 12345 of type <class 'int'> to string column
```

I checked the pytables code that is responsible for converting this to a string and added these lines after line 214 on pytables.py within the site-packages/pandas/core/computation/pytables.py file.

```
    elif not isinstance(v, string_types):
        v = stringify(v)
        return TermValue(v, stringify(v), u('string'))
```

Now the Type error does not exist but it still returns an empty dataframe.

Any help navigating this issue much appreciated :)

Comment: Try this: `query_reporter = "{user_id}='{user_value}'".format(user_id='User ID', user_value=str(my_user_value))`. Pay attention at single quotes: `'{user_value}'`

Comment: Thanks that worked!!